# ADB doesn't recognize my Galaxy Nexus - Win7

Tags: android, adb, windows-7-x64, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I just bought a Galaxy Nexus, now I got a problem, my ADB doesn't recognize it. The Point is when I connect it, it shows it as Storage-Device on my Computer but it isn't listed as an ADB Device.

When I connect my other Phone (HTC Desire HD) it recognize it without any problems.

Some information about the System and Config:

1. I'm on Win7 Service Pack 1 64bit
2. Galaxy Nexus is in debugging mode
3. The Device isn't shown in ADB but Windows recognize it as Massstoragedevice
4. Eclipse and Googlepack is updated to the newest Version

Comment: Have you set the debuggable attribute in the manifest?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: I've got the same problem here. I've installed also the "Google USB Driver package, revision 4" and it changed nothing for me. I got a european version of the Galaxy Nexus (considered as the GT-I9250 and not like in the USA version - SCH-I515). So I am a bit affraid installing bad drivers through the link you provided in your post, jsaye. I've search in the Samsung european website and, as we can see here (http://www.samsung.com/ch_fr/support/model/GT-I9250CWAAUT-downloads?isManualDownload=true), the are no drivers provided ... Congrats to Samsung for making my life easier ;) So do you have an

Comment: I have this same problem but with a Nexus S.  After following the tutorial, drivers are in order, but the phone does not show up as a device under ADB.  Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: yes i just had to uninstall all drivers first, after that i reinstalled all drivers, restarted my computer and it worked. You also could set your phone in Fastboot-Mode, and than plug it to your Computer like this the ADB-Driver should get installed. Best Regards safari

Comment: I get tired of the driver snafu for every new device, I just do this for everything that doesn't get detected: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11874830/322939

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check if you have installed this package in your ADB "Google USB Driver package, revision 4"; if not do it.

Another possible solution could be downloading the drivers from here: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW

This appears to work for the Samsung GT-i9250 version too.

Comment: Thanks, the download from Samsung totally solved the problem for my coworker (works on the GSM version like you mention too).

Comment: It works for me, too, but not all the way.  Trying [this](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/02/12/guide-how-to-use-adb-sideload-to-update-a-nexus-without-root-or-custom-recovery/) to sideload the new 4.2.2 zip, at step 17 it no longer recognizes the device.

Comment: This works for me: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=20058157&postcount=1

Answer (score 22):

If you have previously installed the ADB Driver for the Nexus ("Google USB Driver package, revision 4"+) you may have to manually reinstall it.

The driver is located here:

> android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

Simply follow your os (in Windows Device Manager -> Update driver -> Have Disc -> "Android ADB Interface"

Comment: This worked for me when my Galaxy Nexus went from ICS to JellyBean and I had to force Win7 to take the new ADB driver, all the other options above hadn't worked.

Comment: i can confirm, this worked for me too (i already had the samsung driver installed).

Comment: Failed for me. I did the accepted answer, and that worked.

Answer (score 10):

Go to `android-sdk/extras/google/usb_driver` & replace `android_winusb.inf` with the one downloaded from https://github.com/gu1dry/android_winusb. This will add a bunch of devices, Galaxy Nexus included. Then point to that dir when installing a driver.

Comment: This gets me further than the stock google driver (i.e. Windows 8 detects *something*), so kudos for that. However it refuses to proceed citing `The hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file.`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you have installed the usb drivers for the phone too.
You can take a look at [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) about setting up devices for testing and see if you have missed any of the steps.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is the same and more information as the accepted answer, and was also posted before that.

Comment: The primary problem, for me at least, is that the T-Mobile version of the Galaxy Nexus doesn't have ADB drivers posted ANYWHERE. The link above is for the Verizon version of the phone, and Device Manager says that the driver isn't the right one. But I didn't downvote your answer, so I can't be sure why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

you may try this:
go to settings>Applications>Development>USB debugging(check it if it's not )

Answer (score 2):

try to do this - go to Phone SETTINGS, STORAGE, tap the menu (the three dots in top -right corner, select USB COMPUTER CONNECTION and in the menu select MEDIA DEVICE (MTP). This instantly connected the phone to the computer. Hope this will solve your problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

The drivers for the US Galaxy Nexus (SCH-I515) do work with the European version (GT-I9250M), but you must use a USB 2.0 port. I spent a very frustrating hour trying to understand why the phone wasn't recognized before I tried a different port and everything worked. Only difference, the initial port was USB and the second USB 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Root access in Settings->Devleopment options. Select APPs and ADB.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with the new nexus 10, theses two articles helped me, perhaps obvious but...

Update drivers through SDK manager:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Set up the device on various platforms:
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I just wasted a couple of hours reanimating my Galaxy Nexus.

I was able to access its data. Though, it did not show up as a correctly working adb device. Furthermore, in the device manager, the "Galaxy Nexus" was listet under "Other devices" and no valid driver was found.

I am not really sure what helped in the end BUT: Try wipe the authorized computers on the phone: Developer Options > Authorizations for USB-Debugging.