# Eclipse DDMS not recognising my Nexus phone

Tags: android

Eclipse DDMS Not recognising my Nexus  (samsung)phone .I had install usb drivers externally as well as from device manager. also had conneceted device by usb cable in debug mode still it is not able to recognise in DDMS.please help what to do .Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Do you mean the Samsung Galaxy Nexus phone? Or the Asus Nexus 7 tablet?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801829/adb-dosnt-recognize-my-galaxy-nexus-win7

Comment: @andrewww There's no such thing as the Nexus 7 phone, so I assume you mean the tablet.

Comment: sorry my bad it is Galaxy nexus phone with ics os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Usb drivers from this site

[Samsung Galaxy Nexus usb Drivers](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW#)

also it gives all samsung phone usb drivers.

1)Go to this site

2)Go to the manuals and downloads

3)download exe for drivers

4) install it

5)then connect your device.automatically it installs drivers for apropriate device .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with another phone using Win7 x64. You should check first if all drivers are installed correctly.

Control Panel -> Device Management and check if there's something wrong.

If you use Win7 x64 try to reboot your system and start Window without using Driver signature.
Hope this help you

Comment: I m using win7 X32 . and also i had check in device manager, it is showing my nexus device connected without any (!) mark . also reboot my system not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers got installed successfully and still device is not recognized by DDMS? Here is what worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32519507/1567675