# Eclipse isn't Seeing Nexus 7

Tags: eclipse, driver, updates, nexus-7

I bought a new Nexus 7, and Eclipse cannot see it.  It is appearing in Device Manager as Android Device ---> Android Composite ADB Interface.  There is no other devices category, and I have updated the list.

My SDK Manager has everything except for the obsolete installed and updated.  I have also tried reinstalling Eclipse all together.

I have updated the driver via \adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver and it says the best one is already installed.  USB-debugging is enabled on the Nexus 7.  I am all out of ideas. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall and Reinstall Nexus 7

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Plan B: 
OK you say it didnt work.... this is kind of a long shot but saved my bacon a lot when I was working as a technician in my past life and had to find unknown device drivers.

Right click your Nexus in device manager , select properties and go to this page
[image]

The example shows my radeon card but if you google this hardware ID( the top one in your pc), and check a couple of random sites , you are likely to find it. This method is used for finding unknown drivers, and you may as well give it a shot as you have exhausted most options.

Plan C:
Trying the same nexus on a different windows7 computer to see if it installs . If it does, then you can try to extract it from that computer ( e.g. using driverguide software) and force windows on your main pc to use that.

Plan D:
run `sysprep.exe` on your PC by typing it in RUN and double clicking the file and clicking `Generealize`.This prepares your pc for imaging and removes all drivers. Note that you'll have to activate windows again after this.

Plan E:
And lastly, the call center answer , use system restore, although the damned thing fails 90% of the time and install again after a reboot. or a whole scary reinstall of windows :(

**//Ignore below now as it didn't work for you**

Download this driver http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW

You can also check this question for a solution for Nexus and an alternative driver. I had the same problem , although not with a Nexus, but a sony Xperia, and I had to download a generic driver to get it going. The above samsung site has the driver, but the model is called SCH-I515.  You should be able to fix it without the generic driver 
[ADB dosn't recognize my Galaxy Nexus - Win7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801829/adb-dosnt-recognize-my-galaxy-nexus-win7)

Comment: no luck. any other ideas? (i also tried the driver from asus, who makes this particular nexus)

Comment: Well I say "Ah poop!" I recommend paying Chuck Norris for a hit on Larry Page .... he took your money and gave you a dud phone!